# Using a PC or laptop to send keystrokes to type on Android

Tags: remote-control, external-keyboard, text-input

I wanted to ask if there is a way to use my computer's keyboard to type on my phone while it is plugged into the PC to charge. I was wondering if anyone on here has a setup like this.

The end result needs to be: I can connect my phone through a dock or some other USB cable and either switch between Windows on my PC to type on the Android device or find an OTG device capable of charging *and* connecting a keyboard at the same time. This wouldn't be ideal due to limited desktop space.

I could connect a separate keyboard with an OTG cable, but this would stop me from charging it while using it.

I could also use AutoHotkey or something similar to send keystrokes to the Android device over USB, but I'm not sure how this would affect charging it or transferring files over USB as well. It could probably be done but I don't know where to start.

Ideally, this would be the option I'd use.

Comment: The scrcpy program can both display the screen as well as send mouse and keyboard strokes to the USB connected Android device. I don't know about its Windows version, but Linux version works well

Comment: You can use a remote desktop application like TeamViewer for this. Download the TeamViewer apps on your PC and phone, and connect the phone to the PC. You can put your phone on a wall charger as well, because this method only requires you to have a working Internet connection on your phone and PC.

Comment: Note that TeamViewer has problems with a lot of non-ASCII characters, therefore for entering text it may be not the best choice. Anyway you can simply use the adb  shell for doing so: in an open adb shell just execute the following command: `input text 'your text'`. With a bit of scripting knowledge you could build a terminal that sends all typed text to the device.

Comment: +1 [scrcpy] works well on windows/linux with adb over network (i use it for FireTV). bluetooth keyboard is another wireless solution. i have seen samsung tablets charging and usb-otg at the same time (but most devices don't support this) https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JZND95Z

Answer (score 1):

Use scrcpy.

- Free.
- Fast, no lag.
- If you use autohotkey, you can now use it on android. This is a big one for me since I'm used to [typing with autohotkey shortcuts](https://github.com/onguarde/autohotkey-homerowmod/blob/master/HomeRow%20Mod%20Keys.ahk).
- Drag and drop files to transfer. eg. find the file via "new/recent files" and attach and send whatsapp/signal. This means you don't have to open whatsapp/signal on your PC!
- It works perfectly together with usb thethering or mobile hotspot.

[Github page - Genymobile/scrcpy: Display and control your Android device](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy)

[image]

Comment: Just to note, you'll also need Developer options activated for `scrcpy` and `adb` to work... https://wccftech.com/how-to/how-to-enable-developer-options-on-android-11/